# Next.js working with polyfills and jQuery package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, polyfills

Having an issue that specifically involves the Next.js [array-flat polyfill](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/0af3b526408bae26d6b3f8cab75c4229998bf7cb/packages/next-polyfill-module/src/index.js#L53). I need compatibility with older versions of Chrome, in this instance (v60-68). The application I'm working on uses a video player package that was built using jQuery 3.4. The package uses `$selector).replaceWith(elem)` and is where the error occurs.

[$.replaceWith](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) eventually runs:

```
  var flat = arr.flat ? function(array) {
    return arr.flat.call(array);
  } : function(array) {
    return arr.concat.apply([], array);
  }
```

The problem is an incompatible browser will run `arr.flat.call(array)` because of the Next.js polyfill and will fail inside the `polyfill-module.js` with an undefined reference. When going into the `node_modules/@next/polyfill-module/src/index.js`, removing the array-flat polyfill, and rebuilding; the app will work as expected and run `arr.concant.apply([], array);` as jQuery expects.

So I’m at a cross roads on how to handle the situation. Ideally want to maintain some support with Next's polyfills and migrating from jQuery is a non-starter. Is there a way each can coexist? For example, does Next provide a way to disable the `polyfill-module.js` file from loading on particular pages/instances? Or is there any suggestions to allow jQuery to run as expected in this particular situation?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @trkaplan Yes, posted the solution implemented. Hopefully that's helpful. Also thanks for reminding me to come back and add an answer to this issue

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up for this problem was to remove the Next.js default polyfill for `array.flat` on older browsers as it conflicts with `jQUery.replaceWith()`.

The application I was working in used the [rooks library](https://github.com/imbhargav5/rooks) and [react-device-detect](https://github.com/duskload/react-device-detect).

```
import { useDidMount } from 'rooks';
import {
  browserVersion,
  isChrome,
  isSafari,
  isFirefox,
} from 'react-device-detect';

const MyPage: React.FC<PropTypes> = ({ ...props }) => {

  useDidMount(() => {
    /*
      Remove NextJS default polyfill for array.flat as it will 
      error using jQuery.replaceWith() which is used in the package 
      we are using. jQuery will handle support for browsers which 
      do not support array.flat. 
    */

    //  Stats from https://caniuse.com/?search=array.flat
    const minimumChromeArrayFlatVersion = '69';
    const minimumSafariArrayFlatVersion = '12';
    const minimumFirefoxArrayFlatVersion = '62';

    const isChromeCompatible =
      isChrome && browserVersion >= minimumChromeArrayFlatVersion;
    const isSafariCompatible =
      isSafari && browserVersion >= minimumSafariArrayFlatVersion;
    const isFirefoxCompatible =
      isFirefox && browserVersion >= minimumFirefoxArrayFlatVersion;

    const isTargetedBrowser = isChrome || isSafari || isFirefox;
    const isBrowserCompatible =
      isChromeCompatible || isSafariCompatible || isFirefoxCompatible;

    if (isTargetedBrowser && !isBrowserCompatible) {
      Array.prototype.flat = undefined;
    }
  });

  return <div>...</div>;
}
```